# Running Magic the Gathering Online Beta?

Tags: compatibility

Has anyone been able to run Magic the Gathering Online beta in Linux? The only way I have been able to do it is by running a windows virtual machine.

Comment: A link to the beta would be useful if you want answers and are involved in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the installer, hbdgaf:
http://mtgoclientdepot.onlinegaming.wizards.com/setup.exe

And no, I can't get it to run.

Have only tried wine though, and not for a while.
There have been some updates this summer, maybe it's worth another go?
http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/other/10082013/kiritz

I use a Windows 7 virtual machine currently :(

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.